# Facebook Credits required for all Facebook apps?

Tags: facebook, paypal, payment

There is conflicting documentation on payment requirements for Facebook apps.

On some places, it says all Facebook apps must use Facebook Credits -- and therefore face a 30% transaction fee -- and other places say only social game developers are required to use Facebook Credits.

If you're building an app on Facebook, are you required to use Facebook Credits for payment or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upcoming change applies only to games that run in the canvas element. Facebook is most likely going to require apps in the future use their credit system. Look at http://techcrunch.com/2011/01/24/facebook-to-make-facebook-credits-mandatory-for-game-developers/

Comment: Thanks, we saw this article, too. But since it was dated back in January, we weren't sure if it still applies. We can't find official, current Facebook documentation that states only Games are affected by this and not other apps.

Comment: Given the way they are going, if I was writing a Facebook app today, I'd writing using Facebook Credits, on the assumption that it would be necessary one day.